# Facebook login syntax error

Tags: php, facebook

I am keep geting an this error...

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in 
>       /home/public_html/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on
>        line 146

```
  public function getSessionFromRedirect()
  {
    $this->loadState();
    if ($this->isValidRedirect()) {
      $params = array(
        'client_id' => FacebookSession::_getTargetAppId($this->appId),
        'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
        'client_secret' =>
          FacebookSession::_getTargetAppSecret($this->appSecret),
        'code' => $this->getCode()
      );
      $response = (new FacebookRequest(
        FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
        'GET',
        '/oauth/access_token',
        $params
      ))->execute()->getResponse();
      if (isset($response['access_token'])) {
        return new FacebookSession($response['access_token']);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Here it is , anyone have any idea? I am geting an error that i posted mostly code so i will add this just to get over that... :)

Comment: I aded that couple of lines of code around line 146

Comment: @mrdendi You're a new user I see. If you ask a question about a problem you face, you should (1) tell us what you expect your code to do and (2) add the lines of code where the error occurs.

Comment: sry, just couple of minutes

Comment: Make sure your PHP version is at least 5.4 - that's the minimum requirement for the PHP SDK v4.

Comment: Its worked perfectly on my localhost, this happened when i uploaded website on the domain...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `(new Something(arguments))->immediateMethodCall()` is called "dereferencing" and support for this was only added in PHP 5.4

The fact that you are getting an error here suggests that you are not using PHP 5.4. I'm going to guess 5.3 based on the error message's exact wording.

You must upgrade your version of PHP to be compatible with the Facebook code.

Comment: Just checked , version: PHP Version 5.5.6

Comment: @mrdendi: Is that for your local system, or your production web server?

Comment: That is version that i am running on my local system...Everything worked perfectly there... It seems that web server is running php version below 5.4

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone

```
$response = (array) (new FacebookRequest(
    FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
    'GET',
    '/oauth/access_token',
    $params
  ))->execute()->getResponse();
```

**That is cast the return object as an array** as the later command expects it to be array not an object.